# vb.net: about update .mdb file data using Textbox

Tags: vb.net

i want update .mdb file data using Textbox

```
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=staffdata.mdb"
    Dim sqlStr As String = "Select * from staff"
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()
```

how can i update .mdb file data using Textbox, 
for example:  when i click update button afterinput the password in TextBox1, 
the staff table will update my new password

Comment: There's so much you appear not to know, it's hard to figure out where to start with this. I suggest you get hold of a VB.net book / tutorial and read the databases chapter, about the only bit of the above that might be right for what you want is the connection string, and thats in the wrong place...

Answer (score 0):

its the same as working with a normal sqldatabase, you can use table adapter of any other query you've  learned.